# Python installer not working on windows 8

Tags: python, installation

Python 2.7.x msi won't install on my windows 8 64bit OS(Enterprise edition).
Here is the screenshot.
Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/unable-to-install-any-application-error/fb0ca806-ce16-486f-84fc-5c0d82102f5a:

> *Usually this Microsoft.VC90.CRT error occurs due to corruption in Windows installer* or *.Net framework* Please do not worry I will try
>   my best to resolve it.   However I would require some more information
>   to assist you better.
>
> 1. When exactly do you receive this error message?
> 2. Do you remember making any changes to the system prior to this issue?   I would suggest you to try the following methods:
>      **Method 1:**   Refer the below link to download and install the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable and check.
>      Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
>      http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=ba9257ca-337f-4b40-8c14-157cfdffee4e&displaylang=en
>
> **Method 2:**   Check if the Windows installer service is running on the computer and is set to manual and service is started.   a) Click
>   Start menu in the search box type services.msc and then press Enter.
>   b) In the Services (Local) list, right-click Windows Installer, and
>   then click Properties. c) If the Startup type drop-down list is set to
>   a value of Disable, select the  Manual option from the Startup type
>   drop-down list, and then click  OK. d) Click the File menu, and then
>   click Exit.
>   **Method 3:**   If the above step fails then reinstall .Net framework on the computer and check.   To turn Windows features on or off,
>   follow these steps:   a) Click the Start button, click Control Panel,
>   click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off. If
>   you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type
>   the password or provide confirmation. b) To turn a Windows feature
>   off, then uncheck box next to Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1. c) Later
>   click on Ok and restart the computer. d) After the restart open Turn
>   Windows features on or off again and to turn a Windows feature on,
>   check box next to Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1. e) Later click on Ok
>   and restart the computer.
>   **Additional information:** Turn Windows features on or off

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-address‌​ed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).